# Log MYSQL Login Details

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a tool that logs into mysql but i'm trying to make it log when someone logs in or attempts to could anyone help me with this? It for some reason says can't connect to the mysql says cant find the connection if i add the log code below under the connection info

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {


        string MyConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=password";
        MySqlConnection MyConn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
        MySqlCommand MyCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from bans.toollogin where user_name='" + this.UserTextBox.Text + "' and password='" + this.PassTextBox.Text + "' ;", MyConn);
       MySqlDataReader MyReader;
        string cmdText = "INSERT INTO logs(login, password) VALUES (login, password)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, MyConn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", UserTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", PassTextBox.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MyConn.Open();
        MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (MyReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyReader[count]);
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is correct");
            this.Hide();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and passwor.\nAccess denied.");
        }
       else

        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is incorrect.\nPleas try again.");
        }
        MyConn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

The code i added to try make it log was

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO logs(login, password) VALUES (login, password)";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, MyConn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("login", UserTextBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", PassTextBox.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Never, ever store passwords as plain text.

Comment: oh how would i fix that?

Comment: You want to log it to a table in the database? Simply create a new log-table and write an insert statement then. What's the issue?

Comment: Could you recheck my post pls i made few adjustments

Comment: You are not opening the connection before you attempt to use it with your cmd object.  Also your parameters should be prefixed by an @ in the string. Example: INSERT INTO logs ... VALUES(@login, @time);